# Regex - extract numbers from capture group

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string

```
WIDTH: 700px; HEIGHT: 467px
```

How would I just extract the numbers from it? I have matched just WIDTH: 700px; with the following test:

```
/(WIDTH.+;)/
```

The expected output should be just 700

Comment: just the numbers can come by (\d+)

Comment: That won't work as I need to first capture the width and numbers with it.  This is for an inline style and height and width can be interchanged.

Comment: (WIDTH:\s*(\d+);)   ?

Comment: @user1027217 Please explain clearly what the expected output is.

Comment: you mean this `WIDTH:\s*(\d+)px;`? 1st captured group contains the number you want.

Comment: Honestly, for this, it would be easier without regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match `WIDTH` as it is and then use `\s*` to account for the whitespace characters, followed by `:` and then again whitespace characters and finally the series of digits.

```
var data = "WIDTH: 700px; HEIGHT: 467px";
console.log(/WIDTH\s*:\s*(\d+)/.exec(data)[1]);
// 700
```

Your RegEx matches the entire `WIDTH: 700px`, because you are using `.+;`, which means match any character, one or more times, till `;`.

Comment: @C-linkNepal But [he says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679664/regex-extract-numbers-from-capture-group/25679728#comment40133300_25679664), only 700...

Comment: Yes - none of these are only returning 700

Comment: @user1027217 The code which I posted has been tested on my machine. Please let me know how you verified.

Comment: what about this? console.log(/\d+/.exec(str)[0]);

Comment: @thefourtheye - yea that works, I was using regexr to just test the expression. I'll try it in my code and see how it goes

Comment: @C-linkNepal But [he says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679664/regex-extract-numbers-from-capture-group/25679728?noredirect=1#comment40133236_25679664), `WIDTH` can be anywhere in the string.

Comment: This is the best dynamic choice as it can be anywhere. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex and get the value of width from group index 1,
    WIDTH:\s*(\d+)px;?

Code:

```
> var re = /WIDTH:\s*(\d+)px;?/g;
undefined
> var str = "WIDTH: 700px; HEIGHT: 467px"
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
... console.log(m[1]);
... }
700
```

You could try splitting also,

```
> "WIDTH: 700px; HEIGHT: 467px".split(/WIDTH:\s*|px/g)[1];
'700'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=WIDTH.*?;).*?(\d+)
```

Try this. See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sB4kE6/1